# How to call bash commands from tcl script?

Tags: bash, exec, tcl, interactive

Bash commands are available from an interactive tclsh session. E.g. in a tclsh session you can have

```
% ls
```

instead of

```
$ exec ls
```

However, you cant have a tcl script which calls bash commands directly (i.e. without `exec`).

How can I make tclsh to recognize bash commands while interpreting tcl script files, just like it does in an interactive session?

I guess there is some tcl package (or something like that), which is being loaded  automatically while launching an interactive session to support direct calls of bash commans. How can I load it manually in tcl script files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's going on here is that the `unknown` proc is getting invoked when you type a command like `ls`, because that's not an existing tcl command, and by default, that command will check that if the command was invoked from an interactive session and from the top-level (not indirectly in a proc body) and it's checking to see if the proc name exists somewhere on the path.  You can get something like this by writing your own proc unknown.

For a good start on this, examine the output of

```
info body unknown
```

Comment: +1: This is the start of the trail, but I believe it leads to poor code. Better to have `exec` calls explicit IMO…

Comment: @Donal: Yes, I agree.  Explicit is better than implicit, and I would never actually recommend rewriting the unknown proc to do this, or much of anything else, except maybe to enhance the autoload functionality already present.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to have *specific* utilities available in your scripts, write bridging procedures:

```
proc ls args {
    exec {*}[auto_execok ls] {*}$args
}
```

That will even work (with obvious adaptation) for most shell builtins or on Windows. (To be fair, you usually don't want to use an external `ls`; the internal [`glob`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/glob.htm) command usually suffices, sometimes with extra help from some [`file`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm) subcommands.) Some commands need a little more work (e.g., redirecting input so it comes from the terminal, with an extra `<@stdin` or `</dev/tty`; that's needed for `stty` on some platforms) but that works reasonably well.

However, if what you're asking for is to have arbitrary execution of external programs without any extra code to mark that they are external, that's considered to be against the ethos of Tcl. The issue is that it makes the code quite a lot harder to maintain; it's not obvious that you're doing an expensive call-out instead of using something (relatively) cheap that's internal. Putting in the [`exec`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/exec.htm) in that case isn't *that* onerous…

Comment: Arguably, it's not just against the ethos of Tcl, it's also just poor programming in general.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you should know is that `ls` is not a Bash command. It's a standalone utility. The clue for how tclsh runs such utilities is right there in its name - `sh` means "shell". So it's the rough equivalent to Bash in that Bash is also a shell. Tcl != tclsh so you have to use `exec`.